# Rails 4: Show List of Items in third level associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Following structure in my rails app.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :country
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

I want to access to cities from the country model.
e.g. `@country.cities`. 
Also, how can I get the country from city model?
e.g `@city.country`

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use through option in has_many and delegate for belongs_to:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, through: :states
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :country
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  delegate :country, to: :state
end
```